# wiki inside php application?

Tags: php, cakephp, wiki

Is there any way to embed a wiki inside a PHP application? My specific use is inside a CakePHP framework app. I also need to be able to add custom tags. Anyone have an idea to which direction I should be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a wiki plugin that is easy to integrate in a CakePHP project.

If I were you I would try to install this: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/adael/2011/08/27/adawiki2_an_easy_to_use_wiki_made_in_cakephp and integrate it within the original application.

## EDIT

Pear wiki could be a solution.
You can see the following thread about the resolution of this issue: [how to use Pear Text_wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990159/how-to-use-pear-text-wiki).

Comment: Looking at that, it is just a CakePHP wrapper for the Markdown php plugin, but I can't find a way to extend Markdown.

Comment: @LordZardeck Ok in that case, why don't you take a generic wiki (for php not for a given framework), customize it and integrate it in you app?

Comment: i'd rather not CUSTOMIZE it, but EXTEND it. and that would be fine. Probably preferable anyway.

Comment: @LordZardeck that is close, anyway. Have you got an idea of a wiki that you like so that we can examine if it could be easily extended ?

Comment: I'll take just about anything.

Comment: So why not starting here: http://www.benh.org/techblog/2007/08/top-5-open-source-wiki-engines/. How do you plan to go about extending one of these?

Comment: Okay, i think I just realized I need to clarify something. I don't actually want a traditional wiki. I don't want others editing the article. I just want the engine that renders the markup, and I want to  create custom tags.

Comment: Yeah but generally those wikis can be configured with some access control list than can do whatever you want. But in that case, why don't you use a cms? Could you detail your project?

Comment: I'm working on project which actually contains a number of sub-projects. One of them will be a place where users can write their own articles for others to read, review, rate, and share. But I also want to add the ability to embed certain features of the other sub-projects within the article. I figured the best way to go with this would to use a wiki-style markup engine that I could extend with custom tags.

Comment: I think that you should be ready to do a serious amount of work at least till you understand exactly how the wiki you are using is actually working. There are exemples of such integration but I don't know any open source one.

Comment: I just seen a post to the side under related that may have the answer. it suggested PEAR:Text_Wiki (http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki)

Comment: looks like PEAR:Text_Wiki was what I wanted. If you'll put that in your answer, i'll mark it as the answer